# How to handle future dated records in postgress using Ef core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am working on microservices architecture for payroll application.
ORM -EF core

I have Employee table ,where employee details are stored as jsonb column(firstname,lastname,department etc) in postgress .
one of the use case is, I may receive request for future dated changes.Example- Employee designation gets changed next month but I receive request for those change in current month.
I have two approachs to handle this scenario.

**Approach 1 :**
when I get future dated record(effective date > current date), I will store those records in separate table not in employee master table.
I will create one console application which runs on everyday (cron) and picks up the correct record(effectivedate == currentdate) and update the employee master table.

**Approach 2:**
almost same as approach 1, instead of using a table for storing future dated record, I will update the record in employee master table.
If I go with approach 2,

1. I need to delete existing record when effective date becomes current date
2. when I do get request I should get only current record not future record - to achieve this, I need to add condition for checking effective date. All employee details are stored in jsonb column so I need to fetch entire records with current and future dated record and filter only the current record.

I feel approach 1 is better.Please help me on this. I would like to know another approaches which may fit for this use case.
Thanks,
Revathi

Comment: *I need to delete existing record* -- if there are FKs to this record then you have no choice, it must be approach 1, which sounds more viable anyway.

Comment: Thank you Gert. We are following NoSql structure in our postgres , it's not possible to delete records. So I need to go for approach1